# How to calculate matrix on per-row basis in numpy/scipy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need something like a ternary operator but over a row in a matrix.

I have ai/bi/ci, ad,bd,cd elements, and need to calculate aj/bj/cj:

```
 ai   bi   ci |  ad   bd   cd |  aj   bj   cj 
--------------+---------------+--------------
1.1  1.2  1.3 | 0.1  0.6  0.3 | 1.1  2.4  1.3
                     ^^^             ^^^   
1.5  1.6  1.7 | 0.6  0.7  0.8 | 1.5  1.6  3.1
                          ^^^             ^^^
```

The logic is this:

```
aj = ai if ad < max(ad, bd, cd) else bi + ci
```

if `ai` is max among `*i`, then `aj = bi + ci`. Same applies to `bj` and `cj`, they are replaced with a sum of the other two elements.

I can write a ternary operator in pandas, but hope there is a way to express this in numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [array slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.indexing.html#other-indexing-options):

```
A = np.array([[1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 0.1, 0.6, 0.3],
              [1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8]])

n = A.shape[1] // 2

res = np.where(A[:, n:] < A[:, n:].max(1)[:, None],
               A[:, :n],
               A[:, :n].sum(1)[:, None] - A[:, :n])

print(res)

array([[1.1, 2.4, 1.3],
       [1.5, 1.6, 3.1]])
```

Comment: In general, it's better practice to use `keepdims=True` than broadcasting the result, and should be slightly more performant as well.